# Disable route filters when testing in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, testing, laravel-4

I'm trying to write tests to test API point on the legacy application I've been working on for some time.
Route I have is protected by `auth` filter.

**routes.php**

```
$route->post('protected/route', ['before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProtectedController@someProtectedTask']);
```

**ProtectedControllerTest.php**

```
public function testSomeProtectedTask {
    $routePayload = [...];
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'protected/route', [], [], [], $routePayload)
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

the response I get is "Expected status code 200, got 401" (Unauthorized).

I've tried to add

```
$this->app->forgetMiddleware('auth');
```

to `setUp` and `testSomeProtectedTask` methods without much success. Filters are supposed to be turned off in testing for Laravel but I'm not sure about that and I'm unable to find how to turn them off exactly.

**Edit:**

I've discovered later that my environment was set to `'production'` and not `'testing'` because of tests misconfiguration but the question is still valid since I need to test `'auth'` filter too. 
Tests can be turned on by adding `Route::enableFilters()`. 
More on this [topic](https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/testing-with-laravel-route-filters).

---

**Question:**

Does anyone know how to turn off `auth` filter in testing without commenting it out before tests? Or is there a better way to test API endpoints in Laravel 4.2 and mock authentication somehow?

Comment: You can remove `'before' => 'auth'` from the route, or you can update the `auth` filter in `filters.php` to return true for certain routes during testing.

Comment: I've tried the former and I don't like that since there are some tests that verify route is authenticated. The latter I didn't try. Do you have a suggestion how to do it for a particular route?

Comment: In the auth filter, create an array for excluded routes, then do a check for  `in_array(Request::path(), $exclude)`. If you're working in a testing environment, you can add an additional check to see which environment it's in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @aynber posted some good tips in the comments I still couldn't test `auth` in one test and turn it of in the other.

The solution I ended up with was to mock a user for this particular test.

**ProtectedControllerTest.php**

```
public function testSomeProtectedTask {
    $routePayload = [...];

    $this->be(new \Implementation\Of\UserInterface); //simulate logged in user

    $response = $this->call('POST', 'protected/route', [], [], [], $routePayload)
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```